# User defined database location

Tags: windows-7, vb6

My application, originally created in win XP using vb6, stores program specific values in the registry. One of those values is where the database the program uses is located. The user can put it where ever they like and the program starts it prime the db location screen with the values last saved from the registry. This form uses the DriveListBox, DirListBox, and the FileListBox components. When running this application on Win 7, i am getting an error trying to set the dir list to the value stored in the registry which is a network drive. This all work fine if the drive the db is stored on is local.

The code is:

```
 On Error GoTo HandleError
  dbLocation = GetSetting(App.Title, "Settings", "DBLocation", dbserver)
  If dbLocation = dbserver Then
    Dir1.Path = GetSetting(App.Title, "Database", "ServerDBPath", "C:\")  <----- fails
  Else
    Dir1.Path = GetSetting(App.Title, "Database", "LocalDBPath", "C:\")
  End If
  Drive1.Drive = Dir1.Path
  Exit Sub
HandleError:
   MsgBox "Error connecting to the network.  Check network connections and try again.", vbOKOnly, "Connection error"
   Drive1.Drive = "C:\"
```

I am suspecting the problem is with the directory list box. If i remove my error handling, the error thrown is "Device Unavailabe"

Any ideas on what happening? Are the components I am using not valid for win 7? For this application, the database has to be on a network drive so it is accessable from several PCs running the program. All of the PCs are running on Windows 7.

Comment: Sounds as simple as the drive letter not being mapped in the user context the program is running under.  Modern Windows versions have "split token"  sessions and people often map for the admin context but not the standard context or vice versa.

Comment: What is the actual path value returned that you're trying to set?

Answer (score 1):

The drive, directory and file controls that come with VB6 are hopelessly out of date. They have not significantly changed since VB3 - and that was back in the mid nineties. These were designed for use with Windows 3.1! You would be better off using the Open File and Save File dialogues which come with the Common Dialogues library.

Answer (score 0):

As for the dlls for vb6 provided in windows 7, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx

GetSetting is a VB6 call to the registry.  Windows 7 on a 64bit machine moved the location of the registry for 32bit apps to something like WOW3264.

Comment: The getsetting seems to work, the exception occurs when putting the value froe the registry into the dir list box, yet only when a net work drive is involved. I am running this application on a win 7-32 bit version right now, not to say it wont end up on a 64 bit version.

Comment: i have to research what WOW3264 is, dont think i have heard of it